# Android Master Detail Flow - Select first item in list on tablet only

Tags: android, listview, orientation, tablet

I created a new app relying on the default "Master Detail Flow" template, chosen in the "New Project..." dialog of Android Studio. Then I adapted the application to fit my needs and my data. Works like a charm on handhelds and tablets.

The only thing I want to achive ist to autoselect the first item in the list, showing the detail view and setting the list item as selected.

In the "ItemListFragment" I called the "onListItemClick(...)" method in the overwritten "onStart()" method. This had following behaviours:

- When rotating the device, the first item in the list gets selected (not the previously selected one)
- The list item does not get marked as selected in the list

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this. Because I only want this behaviour in "Tablet-Mode" I guess I have to put it into the ItemListActivity?

Thanks

EDIT: This is my "onCreate" method of the "ItemListActivity"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);
    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
        ((ItemListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is to do that in the main activity only when you know that you are in a tablet orientation. I don't see why are you calling `onListitemClick()` and not `setItemChecked()` on the `ListView`.

Comment: Sounds goot to me. But how do I do that?
In my "ItemListActivity" I use a layout which displays the "ItemListFragment". The fragment contains the ListView, and not the activity. How do I access the ListView in the fragment from my activity?

Comment: The basic master-detail sample does exactly what you want, in the tablet orientation(activity `onCreate()` method), when the second container is present, the activity finds that fragment with the list and calls a method on it which calls `setItemChecked()`.

Comment: After looking at the "onCreate" Method in the "ItemListFragment" I'm still not clear what you mean (see my edited post).

Comment: @Klaus - Did you figure out the answer for this? I am looking to solve the same problem

Comment: @FloydPink: I am sorry to inform you, that I did not manage to solve this requirement. I am also still interested in resolving this issue.

Comment: After posting this comment I researched a little more and could solve these exact same issues eventually, yesterday. Will post what worked for me as an answer... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could resolve this by removing the `onListItemClick(...)` call in the `onStart(...)` of `ItemListFragment` and instead adding this below snippet to the end of `setActivateOnItemClick(...)`:

```
    // If on dual-pane view, pre-select the first item from the chapter list
    if (activateOnItemClick && mActivatedPosition == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().performItemClick(getListView(), 0, getListView().getItemIdAtPosition(0));
    }
```

Also, add this one line of code if it is not already there in `onListItemClick(...)` in `ItemListFragment`:

```
    mActivatedPosition = position;
```

Please check the diff on the file `ChapterListFragment` from these commits yesterday on my GH repo to get a little more context to my solution - https://github.com/floydpink/BhagavadGita/compare/047de35c39f01c6341a7f677aa5b7cc47a7144a3...b1b45d15cd68290e2ebe909ca920bd7aefd2805e#diff-1

Hope this helps

Comment: Great. I adapted my App and your solutions works. Thanks for sharing.