# Select first item in ListView with Cursor Loader

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have an android app that (on tablets) uses the master-detail flow to show a list of forecasts on the left and detailed information on the right. I want to be able to select the first item when the application loads.

I have code in the `onLoadFinished` method that sets the selected index. I implemented this because sometimes the user would select an item, and if they changed the orientation it would be off screen. I used this following method to ensure that once it loads the proper item is selected again:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    // If we have a selected index - select it.
    if(mSelectedIndex != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        mForecastListView.setSelection(mSelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

I tried adding an else statement that checked if a tablet was being used, to select the first item. The code was executed, but it seemed to happen before the listview actually loaded and the item was not selected. Where should I put the code to select the first item, upon app opening?

**EDIT**
Here is a method that I have tried, to no luck:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    // If we have a selected index - select it.
    if(mSelectedIndex != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        mForecastListView.setSelection(mSelectedIndex);
    } else if(mForecastAdapter.IsTwoPane()){
        mForecastListView.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are swapping rather than changing the cursor out?

Comment: I believe you need to use it when you use a CursorLoader if I'm not mistaken. I don't think that's related to what I need to do, though.

Comment: Swapping and changing are slightly different functions, the former retains the previous cursor in without closing it while the latter closes the previous cursor and replaces it with the new one.

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter after it changes?

Comment: Yes. Inside the content provider file, after any changes I have `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` What is the difference between that and `notifyDataSetChange`?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25570170/1777090)

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is called on the adapter after data changes to let the observing classes, i.e. ListViews etc know that they need to refresh. Try calling that after the cursor change but before the index select.

Comment: @MattT. still isn't being selected. I'm baffled. Maybe my mistake lies elsewhere.

Comment: @MysticMagic Thanks for the link, but I still can't put this together. If I call the item click from onCreate like they do, I get a null pointer exception. So I think I'm on the right track, I just need to figure out where and in what method to put this code.

Comment: @McAdam331 Just for giggles, what is the value of mSelectedIndex at the start of your Activity?

Comment: It's -1. I set it to `Listview.INVALID_POSITION`. I set the value in onCreateView based on whether or not the savedInstanceState is null.

Comment: dose your code work for user selection index?

Comment: I mean if user selects index number 10 and rotates his device dose your list select that row after rotation?

Comment: Yes it does. The reason I did that is let's say they're in portrait and the select the bottom row. When they switch to landscape, the selected row may be off screen. I implemented code above to ensure the selected index was set after device rotated so it would be on screen.

Comment: My final question: can you detect your device is tablet or not when you are going to initialize `mSelectedIndex` ?

Comment: I can. I created a public method in the adapter class that returns a Boolean. My Loader methods are in the class for the fragment.

Comment: @mmlooloo sorry I keep forgetting to tag you I forget you aren't notified by default. Also, ask as many questions as you need.

Comment: put setSelection in runOnUithread

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following, I've done it for listviews in general, should work with Cursors too.

In your adapter, create a field for selected position

```
public int selectedPos = 0;//use setter/getter eventually
```

Now make sure that the OnItemClickListener/OnItemSelectedListener for your listView does the following:

```
<YOUR_ADAPTER_INSTANCE>.selectedPos = positionSelected;
```

Finally, in `getView()` for your adapter, do the following:

```
if(position == selectedPos) {
   //do what you want to show selection
} else {
   //do what you want for default state of the list items
}
```

This will ensure that when the list is being shown for the first time, selectedPos will be 0, and as such the first position will be selected according to above.

If you want to persist your user's selection through orientationChange and the likes, you'll just need to make sure that once you are 'restored' you pass on the information to the adapter.

Comment: So you don't think the code belongs in onLoadFinished? Or would it be hack to handle the orientation change stuff in onLoadFinished (because that's where it is and I know that works) and handle the default selection in the Adapter?

Comment: OnLoadFinished should just swap the cursor(or replace like someone mentioned)...this should automatically do a re-layout. Then the selected part should be handled like I suggested. Let me know.

Comment: No luck. I need the code in onLoadFinished to handle what I wanted it to in the first place, getView didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to restore the listview due to configuration change, maybe saving the state would help? For example:

```
private Parcelable mForceastListViewSavedState;
private int mForecastListViewPositionSavedState;
private static final String sForecastListViewSavedStateKey = "ForecastListViewSavedState";
private static final String sForecastListViewPositionSavedState = "ForecastListViewPositionSavedState";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(mForecastListView != null){
        outState.putParcelable(sForecastListViewSavedStateKey, mForecastListView.onSaveInstanceState());
        outState.putInt(sForecastListViewPositionSavedState, mForecastListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    //Restore InstanceState
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mForceastListViewSavedState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(sForecastListViewSavedStateKey);
        mForecastListViewPositionSavedState = savedInstanceState.getInt(sForecastListViewPositionSavedState);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    //Restore ListView State
    if (mForceastListViewSavedState != null){
        mForecastListView.onRestoreInstanceState(mForceastListViewSavedState);
        mForecastListView.setSelection(mForecastListViewPositionSavedState);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do use onSaveInstanceState to store the selected position to handle orientation change. Then, in onLoadFinished() I call set selection. This works when the user rotates the device. For some reason, _when the app first opens_ setSelection(0) does not select the first item.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem ,though  this  question  is  out of  date. my solution is:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader,Cursor cursor){

    mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    if(mPositon!=ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
        mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPositon);
    }else if(mTwoPane){
        {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mListView.performItemClick(mListView, 0, mListView.getAdapter().getItemId(0));                        }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a really good solution! I haven't touched my code for this in a while, but have you verified if this works when the app opens the very first time?

Comment: It's well done.By using this,I solve the problem. Besides,you should  judge the status of device.mTwoPane  is  the statement that you need to know and use.